# Rewrite C code into C# completely or write DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll

Can anyone tell me what would be more efficient: A large program is written in visual-C++ years ago is now intended to be written in C#. What would be better, re-writing the whole code of visual-C++ in C# or write C++ DLLs to be used in C# program via DLLimport?

Comment: *Since visual-C++ is not widely used*  Er, did I miss something?

Comment: A large majority of games you play on Playstation 3 will have been written in C++

Comment: If you need to rewrite something, you would be better off writing it in C#, however if the C++ expose the functions as public API, that you were planning to rewrite, then First: there is no point in rewriting, Second: there will always bugs or miss important logic be introduce when a code is rewritten. Unless there is an absolute need for it, do not rewrite.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was purely my subjective opinion based on my observation because nowadays I see applications being writtin in Java, C# for desktop applications, and for web applications there is a huge list of scripting languages. Pardon me if I offended you. Thanks Jegan for your insight.

Comment: I meant to say with more and more technologies being evolved companies are adopting those technologies rather than using older ones. So if one wants to move from C++ to C# then writing whole applications is useful or writing just the DLLs in C++ and using C# to develop the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on how data-centric your code is. If you can easily separate out the functionality that does not require an interface, then you'd most likely be better off writing a DLL to utilize this functionality, and then re-writing the interface in C#.

If the program is rather interface heavy, and you do not want to go through separating out all of the data functions, then I'd just go ahead and re-write the whole thing in C#, although I'd expect to lose some performance.

VisualC++ is still a very widely used language - is this your only reason for wanting to move to C# (i.e. finding it hard to recruit people, lacking skills to continue development)?

Answer (score 0):

There is only a single answer to this: "it depends". We cannot possibly know this, it's something you must decide.

Check what you need in terms of time and other resources for both. Check what benefit your gain from both. Weigth cost against benefit. Decide.